# Uncheck a group of radio buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jscript

I have 2 groups of radio buttons.
When a button in on group is clicked any button in the other group should be unchecked, and vice versa.

The smartest way I thought would be onclick. But I can't get my head around it.
Any suggestions?

```
[radio button 1 name="a"]
[radio button 2 name="a"]
[radio button 3 name="a"]

[radio button 1 name="b"]
[radio button 2 name="b"]
[radio button 3 name="b"]
```

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
function disableRadioBtnSet(){
  if ($('[name="a"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input[name="b"]').attr("disabled",true);
  }else{
    $('input[name="a"]').attr("disabled",true);
  }
}

$("input[name='a']").change(function(){
   disableRadioBtnSet();
});
$("input[name='b']").change(function(){
   disableRadioBtnSet();
});
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3zyqqkpa/1/)

Comment: Great. I like the idea. But if the user wants to change his selection, he can't. Can you uncheck the selected group?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work only once then not anymore.
The function should uncheck the other group of radio buttons on click and vice versa.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks

```
function uncheckRadioBtnSet(){
  if ($('[name="a"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input[name="b"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).off('click');
  }else{
    $('input[name="a"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).off('click');
  }
}

$("input[name='a']").click(function(){
   uncheckRadioBtnSet();
});
$("input[name='b']").click(function(){
   uncheckRadioBtnSet();
});

<input type="radio" name="a"  value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a"  value="3"><br>
<h6>
separator
</h6>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="4"><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="5"><br>
<input type="radio" name="b"  value="6"><br>
```